# Libreoffice won't start

Tags: libreoffice

Trying to start Libreoffice, I get:

```
/usr/bin/libreoffice: 161: exec: /usr/bin/oosplash: not found
```

I messed up recently with libreoffice by executing:

```
sudo sed -i 's/X-GIO-NoFuse=true/#X-GIO-NoFuse=true/' /usr/share/applications/libreoffice-*

sudo sed -i 's/X-GIO-NoFuse=true/#X-GIO-NoFuse=true/' /usr/bin/libreoffice
```

I tried:

```
sudo apt-get remove libreoffice-core
```

followed by:

```
sudo apt-get install libreoffice
```

Do you have any idea on how I can fix that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove libreoffice-core
```

and then

```
sudo apt-get install libreoffice
```

Comment: I often use the reinstall option of apt-get like: 'apt-get install --reinstall libreoffice-core' in such situations.

Comment: I do not know if --reinstall will force overwrite of configuration files. Any reference on this? (Hint: remove and install will not touch configuration files; purge and install will.)